# How to hook WIN32 WM_SYSCOMMAND and SC_SIZE and still enable window resizing?

Tags: winapi

I'm intercepting (hooking) WMSYSCOMMAND and SC_SIZE messages for my application with intention of resizing child controls as user resizes the main window.

I'm successful at my primary goal, but a side effect occurred: main window is now not resized and user can not drag its borders to do so.

How do I react upon SC_SIZe to resize child controls and not block main window resize (I wan't it to work).

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code - it'll be a lot easier for us to help you if we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Also, why not just pass the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` messages to `DefWindowProc`, per the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx)? *Any WM_SYSCOMMAND messages not handled by the application must be passed to DefWindowProc.* You're looking for default behavior as well as your own custom handling, so just resize your controls and pass the message off to `DefWindowProc` afterward.

Comment: It did help. Now it works and I've moved from detecting SC_SIZE to WM_EXITSIZEMOVE to resize all child controls when user stops resizing the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize your child controls in WM_SIZE and leave those other messages alone (letting them go to DefWindowProc).

There's a user-setting that controls whether windows are updated as they're sized.  If you try to do what you're doing, you'll be overriding that setting, which is a rude thing to do to your users.

If the setting is enabled (which it is by default on modern version of Windows), your top-level window will receive WM_SIZE messages and WM_PAINT during the resize operation.

Comment: Yes, I'm now intercepting WM_EXITSIZEMOVE and returning to DefWindowProc after I'm done resizing my controls.

Comment: @BuzzBubba:  That's the opposite of what you asked for.

Comment: Well, yes - now. I did use WM_SIZING, but to avoid redraw all the time I may opt for WM_EXITSIZEMOVE. Not yet sure what will be chosen for the end result; it mainly depends on performance diff. and UX.

Comment: If you use WM_SIZING or WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, you are overriding the user's selection.  You should use WM_SIZE and do what the user wants.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page. I hook WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, perform child-control size match up and pass the message forward. User still resizes his Window without problem. I'm just resizing border-to-border (by design) control and nothing else.

Comment: @BuzzBubba:  We're clearly not on the same page.  My point is that there is a setting that lets the user decide if he/she wants everything to resize dynamically as they resize the window or if he/she wants the resize to happen only when they finish resizing the window.  If you're resizing the child controls only on WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, then you're bypassing that option.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of it. Thanks! How do I access and read that setting so I know how to react properly?

Comment: Please re-read my answer.  You do not need to check the setting.  You simply do your layout in your WM_SIZE handler, and the system will make sure that's called at the right times, depending on the setting.  The setting is accessed by System Properties -> Advanced -> Performance Options -> Visual Effects -> "Show window contents while dragging".  There's probably a way to check it programmatically, perhaps with SystemParametersInfo, but I've never needed to check it programmatically.

Comment: I see. Sorry, wasn't thinking that way; considered dragging to be separate from window resize. Thanks!